# Excel: How to assign ID numbers from an existing list into another one that contains duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have this list of video game publishers and their IDs.

[It has more than 500 entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U8WT.jpg)

I have a different list of video games in which all games have the publishers from the other list assigned but not the Publisher_IDs.

[Into this list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TLLP.jpg) I'd like to insert the corresponding Publisher_IDs from my other list into the rightmost empty Publisher_ID column.

So in the video game list the first 14 entries would get the Publisher_ID "1" and the 15th entry would get a "2" and so on, according to my publisher list.

I could do it all by hand but that wouldn't be very practical. Can anyone think of a way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Research ``VLOOKUP()``, `MATCH()` and `INDEX()`.

Comment: Read up on how to use [Index/Match](https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index/Match seems simpler to me. Put this in E2 of Sheet2 and fill down:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$8,MATCH(D2,Sheet1!B$2:B$8,0))`

Comment: A slightly modified version of this worked for me :). Thank you very much!

Comment: It's also a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

**You need Reverse Vlookup formula.**

*Write this in Cell E2 of Sheet2*.

```
{=VLOOKUP(D2,CHOOSE({1,2},Sheet1!$B$1:$B$8,Sheet1!A$1:A$8),2,0)}
```

**NB:** Remember its CSE formula so finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, and drag till end also.

Comment: Cute, but surely [the long way around Robin's barn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/around_Robin_Hood's_barn).  :-)

Comment: ,, thanks @Bandersnatch recently achieved here only :-)

Comment: I used INDEX/MATCH as Bandersnatch recommended, but your comment still helped me. I'm still very new to using Excel and didn't know about CSE formulas and needing to drag it down all the way, so thanks a lot!

Comment: it's Okay no problem,, @walidd16 we all are trying to supports each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLOOKUP ([see MS explanation of the function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)). Easier to use if both lists are in the same workbook.

In the MS explanation, they only add the formula once. In your case, you would want to repeat the function down the list so that you cover all entries.

Comment: The usual VLOOKUP() won't work here because the columns are in the wrong order.  VLOOKUP() requires the lookup value to be in the first column of the array, and it returns the result from another column that you specify.  You can use a sneaky trick to reverse the order of the columns (see Rajesh's answer) or you can use INDEX/MATCH where there's no restrictions on the column order.